# How to do a selecting join if two tables have a specfic equal

Tags: mysql, join

Have have two tables in two different databases:

Lets say i have Database `users`, and Database `questions`. If `users` has a table called `USER_STATS` that has

```
USER_ID,
EDU_INT1,
EDU_INT2,
EDU_INT3
```

, and `questions` has a table called `questions` that have a column called CLASS_SUBJECTS.

I want to run a query that will display * from `QUESTIONS` where `CLASS_SUBJECTS` equals either `EDU_INT1,EDU_INT2,EDU_INT3` where the `EDU_INT`'s are determined from a specific `USER_ID`

Any ideas? This is semi hard because of the two different databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When querying across two databases, you just need to prepend the database name with a `.` before the table name as in `database.table.column`, and the database connection user must have access to both databases.

Beyond that, this a regular `JOIN`, but with a more complex `ON` clause using 3 conditions `OR`'d together:

```
SELECT
  q.*
FROM 
  questions.questions q
  JOIN users.USER_STATS u ON (
    q.CLASS_SUBJECTS = u.EDU_INT1
    OR q.CLASS_SUBJECTS = u.EDU_INT2
    OR q.CLASS_SUBJECTS = u.EDU_INT3
  )
WHERE u.USER_ID = <some user id>
```

Comment: I think that would probably work, are the "q" and "u" just as a reference?

Comment: @Linux4Hope They are table aliases, defined just after the tables in the `FROM` clause. Sometimes done with an optional `AS` keyword:  `FROM users.USER_STATS AS u`, but I tend not to use `AS`

Answer (score 0):

The database name reference might work if both are running in the same instance on a single server.  If you need to scale to multiple servers, you might need to use replication and possibly set up federated tables.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-storage-engine.html